# Source code variable search-replace (bash?)

Tags: bash, shell, replace

I am performing some refactoring on a project, and I'd like to automatically replace lots of (mostly) single-use local constants. Using an IDE, I can search-replace, but it requires a lot of clicking, and there are lots of files with lots of variables (all under and only under some folder, so I could apply it to every file on the folder). The following half-baked regex do the desired replacement:

```
Search string: (constant variable string )([a-zA-Z_]+)( = )("[A-Za-z\.]+")(;.*)(\2)(?![a-zA-Z_])
Replacement:   $1$2$3$4$5$4
```

It is ugly and not practical, it only shows the desired behavior: find the declaration, and replace the next occurrence of the variable with its value. I'd need to apply this more than once for every constant, because some are not single use. Lastly, I'd need another search to remove the declaration itself.

I use Ubuntu, so I guess bash would be a nice tool for this, but I'm a Linux newbie, and I couldn't find a script for this type of task. I could also code this in the language itself, but for sure would take much longer.

Could anybody show me the way to do this?
Some example that I could adapt to this case would be great too.

---

Edit: done with PHP scripts the hard way.

Comment: What language and IDE is this for? Most good IDEs have built-in refactoring support.

Comment: @Zac Thompson - Eclipse. That's 'inline' refactoring, but cannot be applied for multiple variables.

Comment: I'll tell you right up front, this can't be done with regular expressions.

Comment: Regex isn't sufficiently sophisticated for this kind of problem. You need an actual parser.

Answer (score 1):

sed is your friend

```
sed -i -e 's/original/replacement/g' files
```

where files can be a glob pattern such as *.c etc.

if you need more power and run into special character problems, you might want to look into perl as well, as the latter has far more tools to do things like this.

Comment: thanks, but this simple replacement command is not enough for my case. I need to find the variables names and replace them further on the file.